# Inspect Element after click

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Okay,

gonna do my best to explain my problem the most clearly possible.

I need to change the CSS of certain element on my website, built in JQuery Mobile.

Let's say I right click a button, select inspect element, chrome opens the debugger and I can see the source. Fine.

But now let's say I want to see the source of a button, WHEN, it is clicked.

Basically, JQuery creates 2 states for a button. For example,

there is this, for a button

```
.ui-btn-up-c
```

and then this, for a button with a mouse hover on it

```
.ui-btn-hover-c
```

Now, I have clickable elements in a list. I was able to do an inspect element and change the CSS, but when I click, there's somehow another class and the default CSS applies. See Picture :

[image]

**tl/dr;** Basically, I'm having a hard time clearly explaining my problem but I'm trying to inspect element on an element when it's clicked...

Please tell me if it isn't clear before downvoting, Thanks !!!

Comment: This can be run as a bookmarklet to allow you to get a snapshot of the button's state: `javascript:$(':button').click(function(){console.dir(this)});void(0);` If the button is a submit button, you could add `return false` after `console.dir` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: you might try adding a www.jsfiddle.net example to show the problem as well

Comment: as far as i know in firebug, when you inspect an element you can see the state change as you put your mouse over or click on the item, I.E  you can actually see jquery addClass('overstate')  not sure how good chromes debugger is for this stuff but you can get a firebug-lite for chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a function that does $(button).addClass(".ui-btn-hover-c") and run it in the console.

Or for a simpler option, you can add classes manually in Chrome's inspector by just editing the code itself within the inspector.

Comment: Accepted answer cause only one thats not a comment ;)